# Why does a null value appear in string output?

Tags: java, string, null, string-concatenation

When I execute the following code the output is "nullHelloWorld". How does Java treat null?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String str=null;
        str+="Hello World";
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: Fancy abuse of the String concatenation rules :) I didn't know that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are attempting to concatenate a value to `null`.  This is governed by "String Conversion", which occurs when one operand is a `String`, and that is covered by [the JLS, Section 5.1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11):

> Now only reference values need to be considered:
>
> - If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).

Comment: For those who are here searching a way to get rid of this `null` at start, simple way around would be initializing your variable with empty string `""` rather then `null`.

Answer (score 7):

When you try to concat `null` through `+` operator, it is effectively replaced by a `String` containing `"null"`.

A nice thing about this is, that this way you can avoid the `NullPointerException`, that you would otherwise get, if you explicitly called `.toString()` method on a `null` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Java treats null as nothing, it is the default value of a String. It appears in your String output because you use `+=` to add "Hello World" to `str`.

```
String str=null;
str+="Hello World";
System.out.println(str);
```

You are basically telling Java: give my `str` variable the type of `String` and assign it the value `null`; now add and assign (`+=`) the `String` "Hello World" to the variable `str`; now print out `str`

Answer (score 0):

my two cent:

```
    String str = null;
    str = str.concat("Hello World"); // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

but

```
str += "Hello World";
System.out.println(str); // Hello World
```