# Array Prints Null - Java

Tags: java, arrays

So I made a name class, and am using an array to store first and last names with the split function delimiting " ". Edit: Sorry its part of bigger project, it would be pointless to copy all of the code. I Have a Person Class thats composed of Name class. The person class utilizes the getStatement below, with println to print it out.

```
public Name(String name){
    String [] nameArr = name.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < nameArr.length; i++){
        if (i == 0)
            firstName = nameArr[i];
        else{
            if(nameArr[i] != null){
                lastName += nameArr[i];
            }                    
        }
    }
}

public String getName(){
        return (name.getLast() + " " +  name.getFirst());
    }
```

The out put for a give name, Joe Shmoe, Comes out to nullShome Joe... I cant figure out why =[

Comment: There is no single line printing anything in the code you posted. So how could we know why you get that output? And we don't know the input, either.

Comment: Please upload the full code of the class so that we can help you.

Comment: ahh, I see, but some of the names on the file im readiing from have multiple last names

Comment: thanks friend, much appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Why does a null value appear in string output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893856/why-does-a-null-value-appear-in-string-output)

Comment: Why do you think `nameArr[i]` would ever be null?

Answer (score 3):

Just initialize the `lastName` property to an empty string in front of the loop:

```
lastName = "";
for (int i = 0; i < nameArr.length; i++){ 
    ...
```

Otherwise, lastName is initially `null`, and the statement `lastName += nameArr[i];` results in `lastName` being set to `null<LastName>`.

---

Actually, you can avoid the loop altogether by using the [String.split() method with the `limit` parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) set to `2`:

```
public Name(String name){
    String[] nameArr = name.split(" ", 2);
    firstName = nameArr.length > 0 ? nameArr[0] : "";
    lastName = nameArr.length > 1 ? nameArr[1] : "";
}
```

---

Another general hint: when building up a string by concatenations in a loop, it's usually a good idea to use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), to avoid [performance penalty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm).

Comment: wow beautiful answer thanks for links

Comment: ...or if you want to build string with delimiter (like space, comma or other) between tokens since Java 8 we can also use `StringJoiner`.

Answer (score 1):

When you append a String which is `null` you get null in it. e.g.

```
String a = null;
a += " hello"; // a = "null hello";
```

In your case you have a `lastName` which was null but is now added a name after the null.

The best way to see what is happening is to step through the code in your debugger in your IDE.  This will show you what each line does.

What you want is

```
String[] nameArr = name.split(" ", 2); // 1 or 2 elements.
firstName = nameArr[0]; // always at least one element.
lastName = nameArr.length > 1 ? nameArr[1] : "";
```