# During field initialization, why "this" is not null and all methods can be called?What does "this" refer to?

Tags: java

My code is like this:

```
public class HelloWorld{

  {
    System.out.println("field init " + this.getName());  
  }

  private String name = null;
  private InnerClass inner = new InnerClass(this);

  private String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public HelloWorld() {
    name = "hello world";
    System.out.println("class init");
  }

  private class InnerClass {

    public InnerClass(HelloWorld hello) {
      System.out.println((hello == null));
    }
  }

     public static void main(String []args){
       HelloWorld hello = new HelloWorld();
       System.out.println("Hello World.");
     }
}
```

As far as I know, field initialization is before constructor, so why "this.getName()" can be called and "this == null" is false?

Comment: `this` is never null because it refers to the instance on which you are invoking the method; if it were null, you wouldn't be able to invoke that method.

Comment: Also, note that there is no need to pass a `HelloWorld` to `InnerClass`: the class is non-static, so it already receives an implicit reference (accessible via `HelloWorld.this`).

Comment: The reason why `this.getName()` can be called and you do not get any nullpointer exception beause `name = null` is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893856/why-does-a-null-value-appear-in-string-output)

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for your comment, besides InnerClass can be replaced by any other Class and the result is same, here is just a example : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There'd be little point to calling an *instance initializer block* if the instance hadn't been created yet, as the purpose of an instance initializer block is to initialize (set the initial information for) the instance (`this`).

So the JVM creates the instance with all fields set to the "all bits off" default, sets `this` to refer to that instance, then does any instance initialization you've specified.

More in [JLS§12.5: *Creation of New Class Instances*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) and [JVMS§4.10.2.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.2.4).

---

Side note:

> As far as I know, field initialization is before constructor

In effect, yes; the Java compiler prepends instance initialization code to the beginning of every constructor you specify.

Comment: can I say it this way, that *this* refers to the class instance, and constructor is just a special method which handles some initialization jobs, this method has nothing to do with the instance creation.

Comment: @YunpengLee correct. The constructor doesn't create the instance: it merely initializes it. ["Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure:"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

Comment: @YunpengLee: Yes. Sometimes people say that the term "constructor" is misleading (in Java and several other languages), because it doesn't really *construct* the instance, it *initializes* an instance that was just created for it by the JVM. So in that sense, "constructor" is wrong and "initializer" would be more correct. But it's not going to change now. :-) The term "constructor" is too well-established (across a bunch of languages).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that all classes in Java have `java.lang.Object` as their (ultimate) base class. Before you get to *any* field initialisation or construction in your class, the `this` pointer for that base class has already been set up.

Hence, it can never be `null`.